# How to use ajax to load new page into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My site consists of two pages. I'm trying to load Page 2 into a div on page one, then display page 2 onclick.  I'm trying to use the following code which isn't working.  I'm a newbie so my apologies if this is just dumb question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url:"myPage2.html",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the URL of your second page really `#myPage2.html`

Comment: It obviously can't be, since `#` is used to separate the URL of the page from an anchor on the page to scroll to.

Comment: try out jsFiddler.net it is good when you have a question like this you can load it there and post us a link. This way people can edit it and work with it.

Comment: No Sorry, it's mypage2.html.

Comment: You're mentioning an external domain in a comment, you haven't mentioned it in your question. Are you trying to load myPage2.html from an external domain?

Comment: Page1 and Page2 are on the same domain.  I didn't use jsFiddle because I don't think it allows me to use two distinct urls.

Comment: You can use [`Plnkr`](http://plnkr.co/edit/) to demonstrate an example that contains multiple files. [I made one for your question.](http://plnkr.co/edit/0AGThF5qXgcZaC4lJLae?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't your code. As you can see in [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0AGThF5qXgcZaC4lJLae?p=preview) it runs without any problems.

The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function can simplify your current code, but it won't solve your real problem, since it's just syntax sugar.

For some reason your browser fails to locate `myPage2.html`, and therefore can't display it correctly.

Comment: Awesome.  I was trying to figure out how to use Plunker.  You got there first.  Hmmm.  I'm onto figuring out why I can't locate myPage2.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Try using your browser's console window, it'll show you if it's erroring somewhere :).

Answer (score 3):

You have a `#` symbol in the load url.

Also, why don't you use:

```
$("#div1").load("myPage2.html");
```

Comment: I think it's really cheap to edit your answer to contain someone else's solution.

Comment: I actually didn't see the other answer until I finished editing

Comment: Yeah.  I originally didn't have the "#" there, it did nothing.  When I inserted a "#", it erased the Page1 but didn't display page2.  I read that you can't use ajax to load from an external domain.  Not sure how to enter page2 url.....

Comment: Correct, that would violate the "same-origin policy".  In most situations, you can only load a page if it originates from the same domain as the the page that is requesting the resource.

Comment: I distilled my actual problem down to this simple exercise.  I'm using $.ajax as i read that .load doesn't work in all browsers.  I can't say as I understand the difference though.

Comment: @user1704787 jQuery is a framework especially designed to overcome browser differences, having an API that doesn't work cross-browser would completely defeat the purpose. `.load()` makes an AJAX call, and just like `$.ajax` they're both restricted to the same cross-domain policies, but other than that work fine everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should work once the `#` is removed from the URL. Here is a slightly more terse version:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").load("myPage2.html");
});
```

see [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I originally didn't have the #.  Didn't do anything.  When I put a "#" in front of the url, it hid page1.

Answer (score 1):

The **#** symbol in *#myPage2.html* is potentially the cause of your error.

Aside from that, if you want, you could also do:

```
$('button').click(function() {

    $('#div1').load('myPage2.html');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("a#button").click(function(e){
  $('#div1').load('myPage2.html');
  e.preventDefault;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!--This is the targeted div -->
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button><a id="button" href='javascript:;'>Get External Content</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

To target an anchor is a better practice than using a div for prompting an action, using alert to test the function as there is on access to the page2.html, however the CORS policy states the file(s) should be hosted on the same server. Tested with jQuery edge, in jsfiddle so it should work still nowadays, can you please confirm later if it was able to load the page2.html into the div?.

Link to jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/0rad93bo/